# How to make all files read-only in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I would like to make all of the files in an Android Studio project read-only, so that if a cat runs across my keyboard it's safe.

In other words, I would like to have the same effect as if I clicked on the padlock icon in the right bottom corner for all of the files in a particular project or a specific folder:

[image]

Is this supported by the UI, or is it conveniently achievable somehow?

Comment: Why not use a version control or local history instead? You can't do it via UI, but you can do it via your file manager / file system utilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mokay, this may have been an strange question... but just in case somebody else is trying to do the same thing:

```
chmod -R a-w app/src
```